# Preload the Image in the webbrowser of  windows phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, browser

I'm designing a news-reading app and using the NavigateToString() of a webbrowser to show some string. Now I want to implement the off-line reading function, the html string had already been downloaded, except the image.

Windows phone has implemented the image-cache function, once the Image is requested, it had been cached. But now problem is that, all the html strings are stored in a array, some of those html strings hadn't been shown throught the navigateToString(), namely the imgs in those string couldn't show up if the internet is disconnected.

So I'm wondering how to cache the imgs in the webbrowser?

thanks,

ellic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ain't gonna be easy or pretty.

Here's one thing you can do...

1. Parse the HTML using something like the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Linq should be a good solution for finding all the images. If you want to use xpath, [you can do that too.](http://socialebola.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/xpath-support-for-the-html-agility-pack-on-windows-phone/)
2. Find all Images in the HTML and use a WebClient (or better yet, a WebRequest) to fetch them.
3. Save them as part of your database that you use to store your HTML strings (say, Base64 encoded if your  medium needs to be strings, key'ed by the URI to the image);
4. When you want to display the offline HTML, again, parse the HTML and replace all references to images with the [data protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) equivalent of your cached images.